# Why are default values not dispatched with UseMethod?

Tags: r

Trying to understand why rownames = FALSE is not passed on from Test to Test.list?

```
Test = function( object , rownames = FALSE , ... )
{
    UseMethod( "Test" )
}

Test.list = function( object , rownames , ... )
{
    browser()
    # rownames is missing!
}

Test( list() )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only actual arguments are passed on to the method. Each S3 method can have their own different default values (which would be a very bad design though).

You should strive to have the same parameters *with the same defaults* as the generic function, and then possibly some extra parameters *at the end*.

```
# Bad design, but possible to have defaults be different...
Test.list = function( object , rownames = TRUE , ... )
{
    browser()
    # rownames is TRUE!
}

Test( list() )
```

Comment: Thanks, Tommy.  This answer confirms what I'm seeing, but I'm wondering why we see this behavior?  Its not obvious to me why default parameters are not passed on?

Comment: Because it's designed that way :) ...and otherwise you probably couldn't check for `missing(rownames)` in your method. ...and now you're free to have other default values (bad idea though).

Comment: thanks!  I guess it is what it is.  I understand that having different default values is a bad idea, its just not intuitive to me that default values are ignored.  Perhaps I need to dig deeper into generic function.  It seems most intuitive that when UseMethod(...) is executed, the parameters of the matched method (Test.list in this case) are matched up to the parameters of Test. Here we are saying "match all parameters EXCEPT when the parameter had a default value.  if defaulted, ignore".  Its just a bit more complicated stated that way. =)